# if string is not in a df column save in new variable - python

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a list with numbers e.g (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) called allowed_numbers
and a column in a df with numbers e.g (1,3,5,6,8,9,10,15,24) B-NUMBER

I would like to save the numbers that dont match in another variable, in this example '10,15,24'

```
fraud = (df['B-NUMBER'] != allowed_number)
```

This gives me an error that the lengths must compare,

```
okay_number = df['B-NUMBER'].isin(allowed_number)
```

this gives me a value of true or false and not a new variable with the good numbers

Comment: What is `print (df['numbers'].head(3).tolist())` ?

Comment: Whats is the output? '['Totals', '001272532129', '001272532129']

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda function with filter values of strings if not match splitted string `s` converted to sets for improve performance:

```
s = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7'

S = set(s.split(','))

df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':['001272532129', '001272532129']})

df['new'] = df['numbers'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(y for y in x if y not in S))
print (df)
        numbers  new
0  001272532129  009
1  001272532129  009
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, this line seems to print df['number']. 

``fraud = df['B-NUMBER'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(y for y in x if y not in allowed_number))
print(fraud)``

Comment: @Monsson - Data are different? Can you change `df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':['001272532129', '001272532129']})` for see problem?

Comment: Yes the data I wrote in the post is not the same as what im working with. The df['numbers'] is a 8000+ column with different numbers and if these numbers isn't in 'allowed_numbers' I need to know that somehow. Thought it would be easiest to store the deviant numbers in another variable :) "change for see problem"?

Comment: @Monsson - Sorry, not understand. There are some another strings and need working with numbers only?

Comment: @jezreal - Sorry I dont understand you. like this: I have column df['B-NUMBER] with 8000+ numbers and I would like to know which of these numbers that isn't in the list with allowed_numbers.

Comment: @Monsson - this exactly do my answer, something is wrong?

Comment: @jezreal - it seems to do the same thing as ``print(df['B-NUMBER])`` for me.